# Can't find subdivide for Blender 2.9

Tags: sculpting

I'm a complete noob. I was following this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGRt24fYYWU
and nothing happened when I pressed cntrl + 4 so I've been looking for "subdivide" but every tutorial I look for has it in different places that don't seem to exist. For instance it's not in the object context menu when I right click.

[image]

Comment: Should be in edit mode to do that.

Comment: @lemon Oh thank you but the guy in the video is able to do while in object mode and his cube turns into a sphere. A wrench icon also appears next to the word "cube" in the scene collection. Do you have any idea how he did that?

Comment: ok, so he probably uses subdivision modifier.Use Ctrl+1 or 2, etc.

Comment: the shortcut: https://youtu.be/mGRt24fYYWU?t=49

Comment: That didn't work for me but I clicked on the wrench while in object mode and clicked on  "Add Modifier", "subdivision surface", and then I changed the levels to 4 and I got the sphere.

Comment: @lemon The link to the shortcut might not have helped him since he followed the tutorial and already mentioned the shortcut in his question... I have a simple idea: maybe myblender used the Numpad 4 instead of the regular 4.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the **subdivide tool**, you must first be in Edit Mode.

- Select the edges you want to subdivide, or hit "a" to select all

  Go to "edge" tab in top left next to what mode you are in

  Hit "subdivide"

For more reading, here is the [Blender Subdivision Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/subdivide.html)

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: But he didn't want to use the _Subdivide Tool_, he tried to follow the tutorial where the _Subdivision Surface_ modifier is added to the cube, using the shortcut Ctrl+4 (for which you have to be in _Object Mode_, otherwise the shortcut won't work). And the _Subdivision Surface_ modifier also creates a rounded, almost spherical cube, what the _Subdivide Tool_ doesn't do by default. You can enable this option but you didn't explain to him how. OF course he can read it in the documentation, but the answer alone doesn't give the result he's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For blender 2.9, select the object you want to subdivide in object mode, press <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> to switch to edit mode. In edit mode click <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> anywhere in the scene and a menu will pop up. Choose subdivide.

You can also adjust the number of subdivisions and other settings by looking at the lower left side of the viewport and clicking on the subdivide word with a drop down to choose what you exactly want.